# BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext]

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying to create my first Spring app. It is showing the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
    at com.spring1.FirstSpring1.main(FirstSpring1.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 4 more
```

**GetterSetter.java**

```
package com.spring1;

private String name;

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}

public void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.println("hello "+name);
}
```

**FirstSpring1.java**

```
package com.spring1;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GetterSetter gt=new GetterSetter();
    gt.setName("Google");
    gt.displayInfo();

    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext");
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
    GetterSetter gt1 = (GetterSetter)factory.getBean("name1");
    gt1.displayInfo();
}
```

The XML file is in the `src` folder.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the actual exception (the exception reported in the original title was simply LOG4J complaining about itself).

Comment: You should use `applicationContext.xml` instead of `applicationContext`. This is what exception says: `FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

Comment: it is working thank you @MichalZiober i replaced applicationContext with applicationContext.xml

Comment: Great, I have added my comment as answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext");
```

Use:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
```